# Copying a C-style string into memory allocated on free store?

Tags: c++

I'm doing an exercise in which I have to copy a c-style string into memory allocated on free store. I am required to do it without using subscripting and relying solely on pointer arithmetic. I wrote the following function-

```
char* str_dup(const char* s)
{
    // count no. of elements
    int i = 0;
    const char* q = s;
    while (*q) { ++i; ++q; }

    //create an array +1 for terminating 0
    char* scpy = new char[i + 1];

    //copy elements to new array
    while (*s)
    {
        *scpy = *s;
        ++s;
        ++scpy;
    }
    *scpy = 0;
    return scpy;
}
```

The function is returning random characters. But if I change it into this-

```
char* str_dup(const char* s)
{
    // count no. of elements
    int i = 0;
    const char* q = s;
    while (*q) { ++i; ++q; }

    //create an array +1 for terminating 0
    char* scpyx = new char[i + 1];
    char* scpy = scpyx;

    //copy elements to new array
    while (*s)
    {
        *scpy = *s;
        ++s;
        ++scpy;
    }
    *scpy = 0;
    return scpyx;
}
```

it works. Can someone explain me why first code is not working and second is working?

Comment: In the first case your are returning 0(NULL). But in the second case you are returning the start address of the string.

Comment: [OT] As the comment suggest, you have sub functions: `char* str_dup(const char*s) { const int len = str_len(s); char* res = new char[len + 1]; str_cpy(res, s); return res;}`.

Comment: `i` should be `size_t` rather than `int`. Actually it is redundant, a `q - s` gives the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code is not working since you return the final value of `scpy`, which at that point points at the terminating NUL character, and not the start of the string.

One solution is to do as you did, and save a copy of the original pointer to have something to return.

You should really use `strlen()` and `memcpy()`, they make this easier but perhaps they're off-limits to you.

Comment: Even if the library functions are off limits to you, you should write the functionality in separate functions.  You can test them and check they are correct (and the `memcpy` or `strcpy` equivalent would have created a copy of the pointer anyway - fixing the problem by accident).